# Trying to reset forgotten MySql Root Password

Tags: mysql, windows-7

I installed mysql, then promptly forgot the password.

I followed the tutorial on the mysql website.

When I enter

> C:> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld --init->file=C:\users\brian\mydocuments\mysql-init.txt

in cmd, I get the message:

> A required privilege is not held by the client

I tried different ways of entering the prompt, and I also considered that perhaps this is because I don't have the right administrator privileges in windows, but when I changed the settings, I received the same message in cmd.  I am confused. What did I do wrong? Everything?  Thank you.

GFB

Comment: can we see your mysql-init.txt , just blackout the password

Comment: UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('*******') WHERE User='root'; 

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run the command prompt as administrator.